# Need help proving if the given series converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have the following number series : $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n} *\frac{(2n+1)!}{4n+1}$$ . I am applying the ratio test and the result im getting is $$ -\infty \ $$ Is this possible ? If not can you help me prove otherwise? Thank you.

Comment: When you apply either the ratio or root test you need to put some absolute values/moduli, so you can't get anything negative (unless you mean the sum, but those tests don't give you that). But anyway, a hint: what's necessary for a series to converge (but not sufficient)?

Comment: Recall that a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ can only converge if $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$.  Is that the case for your series?

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $\lim a_n=0$

$$p\rightarrow q\Leftrightarrow \neg q\rightarrow \neg p$$

If $\lim a_n\neq 0$, then $\sum a_n$ is divergent.

$$a_n = (-1)^n \frac{(2n+1)!}{4n+1}$$

Note $\lim a_{2k}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\lim a_{2k+1}\rightarrow-\infty$, the limit doesn't exsit at all. So the series is divergent.

Comment: So , is it wrong to use the ratio test method?